# Examples of a function whose sum over all rationals is finite?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am looking for functions $f$ such that $\displaystyle \sum_{x \in \mathbb{Q}} f(x)$ is finite. Obviously, $f(x) = 0$ and $f(x) = x$ are two such functions, but are there more interesting examples?

Comment: What makes you think $f(x)=x$ gives a finite sum?

Comment: Not very rigorous but the negative rational numbers must cancel out the positive ones.

Comment: Only if you think $\infty - \infty$ must be finite, and you cannot be sure of that

Comment: Great point, I wonder if there is a formal way of looking at such sums?

Comment: In general you will need to specify an order to sum these numbers, otherwise many functions like $f(x)=x$ dont have a defined value. Check somewhere the concept of *conditional convergence*. Check, by example, [this theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem) about this topic.

Comment: For every $(p,q)$ such that $\gcd(p,q)=1$, define $$f\left(\frac{p}q\right)=\frac1{(p^2+q^2)^2}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac 1 {n^2} & n \in \mathbb N \\ 0 & {\rm otherwise}\end{cases}$$

For a more nontrivial example, recall that the set of rationals is *countable*. Therefore, there it is possible to define a bijection $\phi: \mathbb N \to \mathbb Q$. Choose any such bijection $\phi$, and define
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac 1 {\phi^{-1}(x)^2} & x \in \mathbb Q \\ 0 & {\rm otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 4):

Write each $q$ as $\dfrac{a}{b}$ with $a,b$ coprime integers and $b \gt 0$

Then for example $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{(a^2+1)b^2}$ will have a finite sum over the rationals

Comment: Nice! Great idea.